# LEFT JOIN Not including all rows of left side table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a BigQuery query that produces a minute-by-minute table of average slot usage for a specific BigQuery reservation. I want a count, even if it's 0, for each minute. What's confusing me is I'm not getting every minute in the output.

```
WITH
  minutes AS (
  SELECT
    ts
  FROM
    UNNEST( GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ) AS ts)
SELECT
  minutes.ts DAT,
  SUM(total_slot_ms/TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,creation_time,MILLISECOND)) AVG_SLOT_USAGE,
FROM
  minutes
LEFT JOIN
  `fake-project-id.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` job
ON
  job.creation_time <= minutes.ts
  AND job.end_time >= minutes.ts
WHERE
  reservation_id = "fake-res-id"
GROUP BY
  minutes.ts
ORDER BY
  minutes.ts desc
```

The output I get is:

```
[{
  "DAT": "2023-04-12 21:10:21.081712 UTC",
  "AVG_SLOT_USAGE": "0.11194029850746269"
}]
```

I'm expecting to see a DAT value for every minute in the past 10 minutes. In fact, when I select just from the minutes temp table, I get all 10 minutes:

```
[{
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:04:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:05:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:06:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:07:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:08:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:09:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:10:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:11:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:12:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:13:40.598227 UTC"
}, {
  "ts": "2023-04-12 21:14:40.598227 UTC"
}]
```

This violates my understanding of LEFT JOIN. Isn't LEFT JOIN supposed to give me a row for every record in the left side table, regardless of whether there's a matching record for the ON clause in the right side table?

Comment: Have you tried it after removing `WHERE` condition ?

Comment: Yes, there are still gaps, but not as many. But that's the thing that's happening and is not according to SQL spec, according to my understanding. Every row of the left side table should be included regardless of the WHERE clause of the right side table.

Comment: `WHERE` clause is evaluated later after `JOIN` on `FROM` clause, so it can filter out some result from the output of LEFT-JOIN.